# Запрет повторной установки интервала

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Есть картинка на странице. Она вращается по клику на определенный градус (через таймер). Как мне обезопаситься от дублирования таймера при повторных кликах на картинку?

Фрагмент скрипта:

```
var $rot = 0;
var $tim3;

function rotkar($kol) {
    $rot = $rot + $kol;
    document.getElementById('kar').style.transform = "rotate(" + $rot + "deg)";
} //'kar'- это картинка

function clickar() {
    $tim3 = setInterval("rotkar(7);", 1000);
}

function $trot() {
    clearInterval($tim3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, при клике проверять, есть ли ID интервала в переменной `$tim3`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var $rot = 0;
    var $tim3;
    var image = document.getElementById('kar');
  
    function rotkar($kol) {
        $rot += $kol;
        image.style.transform = "rotate(" + $rot + "deg)";
    }
  
    image.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if ($tim3 == undefined) {
            $tim3 = setInterval(function() {
                rotkar(7);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<img id="kar" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
```

- Добавлять обработчик события через `onclick` - не лучшая затея.
- Передавать строку в качестве первого параметра `setInterval` и `setTimeout` - тем более.

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Как бы сделать так, чтобы после отмены таймера можно было снова кликнуть на картинке и она стала вращаться.

Comment: @лихаим на здоровье. Добавьте в функцию `$trot` строку `$tim3 = undefined;` после `clearInterval($tim3);`.